# Google BigQuery SQL -

Tags: google-bigquery

P2_PCM_C_L112_2011_00_1v
P2_PCM_L212_2012_00_1v
P2_PCM_C_L119_2011_00_1v
P2_PCM_L6712_2012_00_1v
P2_PCM_C_L17612_2014_00_1v

using Regular Expressions I would like to separate and place into rows, separated by the underscore. For example if I was only interested "PCM" the year "2011"and "1v" as each row is different lengths but hold the info I need.

What would the code be for legacy SQL (its for google BigQuery)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to just use `LIKE` here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE col LIKE '%\\_PCM\\_%\\_2011\\_%\\_1v';
```

This would match any input having the components `PCM` and `2011` in the middle of the string and `1v` at the end.